# intellij flags properties set by maven-resources-plugin as "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-resources-plugin

In my project's POM, I use maven-resources-plugin to set some properties from a file.  However, Intellij flags these property references in the POM with the error "cannot resolve symbol", presumably because it cannot see them being defined anywhere.  Is there a way to suppress this error?

Comment: If you hit alt-enter, is there an option where you can disable the inspection?

Comment: @vikingsteve no, the only options are "merge tags" and "split current tag"

Comment: Wondering then if you are able to define them with blank values and then overwrite them with the maven-resources-plugin?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can open *Settings* (spanner icon), go to *Project Settings* -> *Inspections* and then disable the inspection *Maven* -> *Maven Model Inspection*.

Alternatively, you might like to try defining "blank" values for the properties, and see if the plugin successfully overwrites them.

```
<properties>
     <myproperty></myproperty>
</properties>
```

Good luck!

Comment: The setting didn't have any effect for me, but the empty property worked.

Comment: Sry, but this solution isn't correct! Please see my Answer below.

Answer (score 6):

**Warning**: The solution to define the property blank as *vikingsteve* mentioned is very dangerous because in Maven 3 properties which are declared in `pom.xml` could not be changed by other plugins.

So if you have one plugin which sets a property and another plugin which reads the value of the property it will always get an empty string if you initialize it in the `pom.xml`.

In fact you can't define it in the `pom.xml` but i have no idea what i can do to eliminate the IntelliJ IDEA warning. For now i have to disable the "Maven model inspection". :-(

Comment: did you ever find a better resolution?

Comment: unfortunately, not yet. sry.
I also don't know if there exists a JIRA ticket at jetbrains... :(

Comment: @ the user who have down-voted my answer (maybe @vikingsteve ?): can you please explain why you have down voted my answer? I can't see any error.

Comment: probably because you were unfortunately also not able to provide a better solution, a final answer

Answer (score 0):

The best way I see to solve the issue is to use the following comment:

```
<!-- suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
```

Empty properties are not overwritten or may be a risky operation as @Josef mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Error “cannot resolve symbol” can occur if you open a directory maven project, but intellij project has not yet been created. Why does the "Maven model inspection" there is such a relationship - is not clear, but it helped me.

Comment: Hey Stas, in either case you should edit this and clarify what you mean by the model inspection. I can't tell if you're asking a question or proposing a solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: I mean, that there is a project - "Inspection" is working correctly. There is no "idea"-project, the properties are highlighted as "cannot resolve symbol".